# why prototype has to be declared outside of the constructor?

Tags: javascript, prototype

havng such a code:

```
function A(){
  var a=7;
  this.fun = function(){
    return a*2;
  }
}

function B(){
  var a =8;

}
```

it is obvous that in order to refernce B prototype to A we need to add a line:

```
B.prototype = new A();
```

I am wandering why it is not valid to make such a code:

```
function A(){
  var a=7;
  this.fun = function(){
    return a*2;
  }
}

function B(){
  var a =8;
  this.prototype = new A();
}
```

when we would need to put prototype inside declaration on B, we would need to make it via:

```
function B(){
   var a =8;
   this.__proto__ = new A();
}
```

and such code will not work:

```
function B(){
  var a =8;
}
B.__proto__ = new A();
```

and now I am loosing it - why it is like that? Why we have to declare prototype outside of a function and we cannot declare it within, and why it is just opposite for **proto** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) var A = function () {
   this.x = function () {
      //do something
   };
};

2) var A = function () { };
   A.prototype.x = function () {
     //do something
  };
```

In first case, variable A is assigned a value that is a reference to a function. When that function is called using A(), the function's this isn't set by the call so it defaults to the global object and the expression this.x is effectively window.x. The result is that a reference to the function expression on the right hand side is assigned to window.x.

In the second case, in the first line, variable A is assigned a reference to a function. In JavaScript, all functions objects have a prototype property by default so there is no separate code to create an A.prototype object.In the second line, A.prototype.x is assigned a reference to a function. This will create an x property if it doesn't exist, or assign a new value if it does. So the difference with the first example is which object's x property is involved in the expression.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer,Mark the question as accepted :)